# Deeppavlov - make custom intents

Tags: python, nlp, chatbot, deeppavlov

```
from deeppavlov import build_model, configs

snips_model = build_model(configs.classifiers.intents_snips , download=True)
snips_model(["Hello! What is the weather in Boston tomorrow?"])
```

Hello All - I can use deeppavlov's pretrained model above for intent classification with pre-created intents. However, I want to use deeppavlov to create my own intent classification model with my own intents and own text. There will be 5 to 7 total intents.

How would I go about doing this?

ie sample data i've got with text and intents

```
text,intent
Where is McDonald's?, resturant
What is the weather today, weather
Where is the closest Burger King?, restaurant
Is it sunny today?, weather
What is the temperature today?, weather
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late answer. If still relevant, you may consider the following tutorial for custom classification:
https://github.com/deepmipt/DeepPavlov/blob/master/examples/classification_tutorial.ipynb

There are several different embedding methods and models.
You may also try to implement your own dataset as in the tutorial, and use model more actual models like BERT- based classification, see `_bert` configs in the directory https://github.com/deepmipt/DeepPavlov/tree/master/deeppavlov/configs/classifiers

Answer (score 2):

We have a new model/NLP component called Intent Catcher shipped in v0.14 of DeepPavlov Library. With it, you can provide your own intents (currently within the JSON format but we'll provide a more human-readable format in YML soon), and then train classification model based on your intents. The good thing is you can use it to also auto-generate more examples by using RegEx.

You can learn more about Intent Catcher here:

http://docs.deeppavlov.ai/en/master/features/models/intent_catcher.html

Here's the tutorial on how to use it:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1l6Fhj3rEVup0N-n9Jy5z_iA3b1W53V6m?usp=sharing

Let us know if that works or not for you

Answer (score 0):

Training `intents_snips` model requires a training dataset. I would recommend, before collecting the data, try using lightweight the FAQ model, where few training examples per class is enough.

`from deeppavlov import configs, train_model`

`faq = train_model(configs.faq.tfidf_logreg_en_faq)`

`a = faq(["I need help"])`

Details can found [here](https://medium.com/deeppavlov/simple-intent-recognition-and-question-answering-with-deeppavlov-c54ccf5339a9)